# Using PHP session to display status messages

Tags: php, html, session

I'm trying to display a submission status above my contact form, so my plan is to use sessions, but it's not working properly. The form successfully submits, and the page gets successfully redirected back to the demo.htm page (after it was redirected to index2.php), but no status message is ever diplayed.

I was also going to use the session in order to display required tags on blank fields since iOS doesn't support the 'required' input tag (The giant commented out chunk of the html form will replace the current form fields to handle the required fields on iOS).

UPDATE: There's something strange going on with echo.... Could it be something with the php.ini file (if so, what?)?

Input#1:

```
 <p>Text Here</p>
<p><?php echo($_SESSION['status']); ?></p>
<p>Temp</p>
<p id="status">
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['status'])){
        echo("<br/>"$_SESSION['status']."<br/>");
        unset($_SESSION['status']);
    }
?>
</p>
<p>More text here</p>
```

Output #1:

```
Text Here

Temp

"$_SESSION['status']."
"); unset($_SESSION['status']); } ?>

More text here
```

Input #2:

```
<?php echo strcmp("Hello world!","Hello world!")."<br/>"; ?>
```

Output #2:

```
"; ?>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 $firstName = $lastName = $email = $companyName = $jobTitle = $phoneNumber = $comments = "";
 $noErrors = true;

 if($_POST['submit']) {
    if(empty($_POST["firstname"])) {    $_SESSION["nameErr"] = "First name is required"; $noErrors=false;} 
    else {                      $firstName = $_POST['firstname']; }
    if(empty($_POST["lastname"])) {     $_SESSION["lastErr"] = "Last name is required"; $noErrors=false;}
    else {                      $lastName = $_POST['lastname']; }
    if(empty($_POST["email"])) {        $_SESSION["emailErr"] = "Email is required"; $noErrors=false;}
    else {                      $email = $_POST['email']; }
    if(empty($_POST["companyname"])) {  $_SESSION["companyErr"] = "Company name is required"; $noErrors=false;}
    else {                      $companyName= $_POST['companyname']; }
    if(empty($_POST["position"])) {     $_SESSION["jobErr"] = "Job title is required"; $noErrors=false;}
    else {                      $jobTitle = $_POST['position']; }
    if(empty($_POST["number"])) {       $_SESSION["phoneErr"] = "Phone number is required"; $noErrors=false;}
    else {                      $phoneNumber = $_POST['number']; }

    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $header = "From: xxxxx.com";
    $to = 'xxxxx.com';
    $subject = 'Demo request';

    $message = "From: \r\n 
        Name: $firstName $lastName\r\n 
        E-mail: $email\r\n 
        Company Name: $companyName\r\n 
        Job Title: $jobTitle\r\n
        Phone Number: $phoneNumber\r\n
        Comments: $comments";

    if(($noErrors == true) && mail ($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Your message has been sent!";
        header('Location: demo.htm');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['status'] = "Something went wrong, please try again";
        header('Location: demo.htm');
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>*stuff*</head><body>
<p id="status">
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['status'])){
        $echo $_SESSION['status'];
        unset($_SESSION['status'];
    }
?>
</p>

<div id="requestADemo">
    <p style="line-height: 2%; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 200;">Request A Demo</p>
    <p style="line-height: 2%; font-style:italic; font-size: 13px;">*indicates required field</p>

    <form method="post" action="index2.php">
        <!--p class="demo" style="margin:0;">First Name:*</p>
            <input type ="name" name="firstname" required>
            <span><?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['nameErr'])){
                    $echo $_SESSION['nameErr'];
                    unset($_SESSION['nameErr'];
                }
            ?></span>
        <p class="demo">Last Name:*</p>
            <input type ="name" name="lastname" required>
            <span><?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['lastErr'])){
                    $echo $_SESSION['lastErr'];
                    unset($_SESSION['lastErr'];
                }
            ?></span>
        <p class="demo">Email:*</p>
            <input type ="email" name="email" required>
            <span><?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['emailErr'])){
                    $echo $_SESSION['emailErr'];
                    unset($_SESSION['emailErr'];
                }
            ?></span>
        <p class="demo">Company Name:*</p>
            <input type ="name" name="companyname" required>
            <span><?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['companyErr'])){
                    $echo $_SESSION['companyErr'];
                    unset($_SESSION['companyErr'];
                }
            ?></span>
        <p class="demo">Job Title:*</p>
            <input type ="name" name="position" required>
            <span><?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['jobErr'])){
                    $echo $_SESSION['jobErr'];
                    unset($_SESSION['jobErr'];
                }
            ?></span>
        <p class="demo">Phone Number:*</p>
            <input type ="number" name="number" required>
            <span><?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['phoneErr'])){
                    $echo $_SESSION['phoneErr'];
                    unset($_SESSION['phoneErr'];
                }
            ?></span>
        <p class="demo">Comments:</p>
            <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Type Here" rows ="10" columns="50"></textarea>
        <p class="demo"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p-->



        <p class="demo">First Name:*<br/><input type ="name" name="firstname" required></p>
        <p class="demo">Last Name:*<br/><input type ="name" name="lastname" required></p>
        <p class="demo">Email:*<br/><input type ="email" name="email" required></p>
        <p class="demo">Company Name:*<br/><input type ="name" name="companyname" required></p>
        <p class="demo">Job Title:*<br/><input type ="name" name="position" required></p>
        <p class="demo">Phone Number:*<br/><input type ="number" name="number" required></p>
        <p class="demo">Comments:<br/><textarea name="comments" placeholder="Type Here" rows ="10" columns="50"></textarea></p>
        <p class="demo"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
    </form> 
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Also where are you setting the `$_SESSION['status']`?

Comment: "it's not working properly"? what is the problem?

Comment: The formatting got messed up when I pasted the code, session_start is there in both and I set 'status' at the very end of the php code in the if/else. Nothing is displayed when I submit the form (which is successfully submitted).

Comment: can you edit your question to give us a guide as to which pages are `.php` pages and which pages are `.htm` pages

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. I labeled the pages as PHP/HTML.

Comment: so the page code above entitled "HTML" is a `.htm` page?

Comment: Yes it is, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML pages will not parse PHP data/syntax unless specifically told to via `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` or some similar server level association methods.

You are trying to display the PHP `SESSION` data within a HTML page, which is not going to happen until you tell the html page to interpret PHP code.

[This StackOverflow question gives you clear guides on how to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files).

If your `demo.htm` is just a HTML page with no ability to handle PHP then you will see output (including all the PHP code) *as if it was only HTML*.

Example:

**demo.html (from your question):**

> ```
> <?php
>  session_start();
>  ?>
> <!DOCTYPE html><html>
>  <head>*stuff*</head><body>
> <p id="status">
>  <?php 
>  if(isset($_SESSION['status'])){
>        echo $_SESSION['status'];
>   unset($_SESSION['status'];
>   }
>  ?>
>  </p>
> ```

This is being treated as HTML and so will produce a mess of output due to the `<` and `>` being HTML parser opening and closing tags.

I have also removed the `$` from the `echo` statement as echo is a function not a variable.

### Solution:

While the link I give above is useful, it is quickest and easiest to simply rename your `demo.htm` to `demo.php` to indicate to the server to parse the page as a PHP page. You will need to update links to the page (such as the form action tag) but it will mean the page will be correctly processed by the server.

Comment: Would there be any issues with just making it a .php file instead? That's fine by me if it's not going to break functionality of anything else. (And it does work perfectly when it's .php, thanks).

Comment: as long as your anchors on other parts of your site have the correct anchor link destination name (`file.php` rather than `file.htm`) then no, it would not cause any issues. @djd97

Comment: Alright, perfect. Thanks. Oh, I did notice one thing the .php file will fail to load if there are any typos anywhere on the page since it's no longer html. Is there any way to prevent that -- i.e. is there anyway to make just the element where the typo exists look broken rather than preventing the whole page from rendering?

Comment: Also, I've actually got a somewhat related question. How would I prevent it from clearing the input fields if the input was not correct? The way I have it set up now is if any of the fields are incorrect the else at the very end of my index.php file will execute and then my demo.php file will have all the fields emptied (as well as having notices next to any field that needs correcting). @Martin

Comment: 1) please read up on [PHP Error logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) .The whole page fails to load because PHP found a fatal error that killed the script (Or possibly your data-processing logic is flawed).

Comment: 2) You would need to use something like in the form (if HTML5) use autocomplete or when the form submits, the page it submits to loads all the `$_POST` data into a PHP `$_SESSION` array and you can then edit the form page to load the session data. Can be useful if session data is saved using AJAX every few seconds or so.

Comment: (your comment question 2 is really a question in its own right) - There are answers on StackOverblow on that topic `:-)`

Comment: Okay, so if one of the fields is blank, I'll save the $_POST values into $_SESSION values. How would I then fill in the input fields with the $_SESSION values (which will either be empty strings or inputs)? Yeah, I know it is it's own question, but I'd rather not get locked out of asking questions for 90 minutes just in case.

Comment: why do you get locked out of asking questions? `:-/`

Comment: search SO for "how to save unsubmitted form data [php] [html]"

Comment: I'm restricted to one question every 90 minutes (until I have more posts I guess). And thanks :)

Comment: I figured everything out. Thanks so much.

Comment: I didn't know that about the 90-minute restriction. Glad you got it all sorted though `:-)`